# Context initialization error in WebSphere 9.0

Tags: spring, websphere

I am migrating a Spring 3 application to Spring 5 and all works fine with tomee 8 but when i deploy the same WAR file in WebSphere 9.0.0.5, there is context initialization errors. But the application is shown as started with green arrow. My beans are annotated with @Component, @Service and @Respository and i have component scanning as below:

<context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.xyz" use-default-filters="true">
<context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>

The controllers are loaded using another webmvc.xml.

The auto-wiring of the beans into controller is getting failed.

List of trouble shootings done:

- Verified FFDC couldn't find any leads
- Checked the class loader viewer under troubleshooting option and all classes from WEB-INF/classes and WEB-INF/lib loaded including the class failing to be injected is already loaded.
- Enabled root logger with error and no error could be found and the root logger is working fine when i enable Debug with whole lot of logs generated.
- Removed the spring related jars and moved as a shared library at server level and set the class loading policy as parent last and noticed those spring classes were loaded by WAS boot strap class loader.
  Suspecting the component scan causing issue.

Thanks in advance for any help in identifying the issue..

Comment: There are two application servers under the WebSphere "brand" name: WebSphere Application Server traditional, and WebSphere Liberty.     It sounds like you're describing the traditional product, which is the one with the "admin console" application used to deploy apps and manage the environment.  As a starter, have you browsed through this documentation:  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/cspr_intro.html  ?    Maybe you could paste some of the errors too.

Comment: The problem got resolved as the class path seems to be different when deployed as WAR in tomee versus WAR in Websphere. In Websphere, the WAR is deployed as enterprise application which Websphere deploys as EAR. The different code snippet are as `classpath:context-*.xml` versus `classpath*:/WEB-INF/classes/context-*.xml` The deployment is in ND not on Liberty.